# Ionic App not working in Mobile but Works in Browser

Tags: php, web-services, http-headers, ionic3, httpservice

I have created an app for the Registration Form using [Ionic + PHP] and I face the following issue.

**CORS Add-on: Activated** - It works Fine when I use it in the `http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab`
**CORS Add-on: Deactivated** - It does not works Fine when I use it in the `http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab` and the below mentioned error occurs.

Below I will explain the codes in my Files.

**remote-service.ts**

```
constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.headers = new Headers()
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100')
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD')
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
    this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    console.log('Hello RemoteServiceProvider Provider');
  }

getAllUsers() {
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers })
    return this.http.get('http://haitutorial.com/HybridApp/listAllUsers.php', options)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

getAllUsers() - This function will fetch all the users Registered from the specific URL.

**database.php**

```
<?php
include('database.php');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
header('Accept','application/json');
header('content-type','application/json');
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status`='1' AND `delete_status`='0' ORDER BY `user_id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$resultant_array = array();
if($count>0)
{
    while($informations = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $resultant_array[] = $informations;
    }
    print_r(json_encode($resultant_array));
}
else
{
$resultant_array[] = ["success"=> 200, "message"=> "No Data Found", "status_code"=>1 ];
echo $output = json_encode($resultant_array);   
}
?>
```

The Above URL mentioned in the `getAllUsers()` works in the Browser but when placed inside the Ionic App it shows the below Error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://haitutorial.com/HybridApp/listAllUsers.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

The above Issue is solved when I **enable** the **CORS add-on** in the Browser. But when I **Disable** the **CORS add-on** in the Browser it shows the **Error**.

Like wise the Same Error prevails in the Insert Page Also. When I Insert the Data from the APP it redirects to the List Page and the Data are not displayed telling the above said Error.

I have added `header()` in the PHP File also. But I am unable to trace out the Error. I am in need to Fix this Error without the use of Add-on like stuffs in the browser and needs to run successfully in APP too.

Comment: The GET Request automatically changes to OPTIONS Methods and that is the reason for this Error.  Kindly provide me with the solution of how to retain back the `GET` HTTP call as GET itself when the response comes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/4826457

Comment: remove Access-* and Accept headers from ionic.. those are only server side

Comment: How to accpet headers from ionic. I have removed the Access.* From the headers but it does not solve my request @Suraj Rao

Comment: Could any one kindly share me the solution. Since I am unable to find the solution for past 3 days. Very Desperate need of Solutions.

Comment: Options is a preflight CORS request and is normal.. you need to see the linked answer and implement something similar in your server side..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: So that means I do not change anything in the Ionic Part of the Code. I have to double check the PHP part Alone right @Suraj Rao

Comment: yes...thats true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164964/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-suraj-rao).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set header at server end not ionic side.

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");

Comment: By doing this also the same error prevails. If I activate the add-on alone the page works otherwise it shows CORS error alone. Kindly share some other thoughts regarding this.